# Why is there a DC power supply installed in my new home?

Tags: electrical

I've moved to Ireland and have noticed this box in the electrical area of the property - I've never seen this before - anyone know what its purpose is, if it is needed and what device could be using such a unit?

[image]

Comment: It obviously provides up to 1 Amp of 12VDC power to some device. Is there anything nearby that might need that? It would be small.

Comment: Trace the output wire and see what it connects to.  That will likely answer your question.  But something like an alarm system comes to mind.

Comment: I would guess it is for LED lighting or a fancy doorbell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that it's got indicators for "battery fault" and "manual battery test" almost certainly an alarm, probably a fire/smoke/CO (life safety) alarm though a "mere" burglar/intrusion type alarm might well also have such a thing - or the two types might be combined in the same system.

Edge case - power for a fiber-optic telephone/network circuit device, so your phone works when the power is out, for a while. But in that case I'd expect to see a telephone company label on it. And past questions have indicated that they mostly just beep in a "hard to locate" way rather than having clear indicator lights.

Is it needed? It wasn't put there for giggles. Whatever it powers will stop working if you remove power to it or remove it. That thing might well be important.